# devise not working for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have no idea what I did to do this but I can't figure this out for the life of me, I've deleted any files that had to to with devise, restarted server and tried again, and same thing keeps happening. I am using nitrous.io and this is the error i am receiving:

```
action@pink-wheels-17-155067:~/hellorails(hope*)$ rails generate devise:install                                         
/home/action/hellorails/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `devise_for' for #<ActionDis
patch::Routing::Mapper:0x007f2ca48b42c8> (NoMethodError)
```

and then a bunch of error message like this following:

```
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'                      
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'     
        from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `requir
e'                                                                                                                      
        from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `requir
e'                                                                                                                      
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

and when I go in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :install
```

which I have to assume is a good thing because this wasn't here before I did "bundle install"

but how can I fix this? Any help is appreciated. When I was installing it I accidentally did "rails generate devise: install" instead of "rails generate devise:install" not sure if that matters but it's all i did.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like devise thinks the model you are trying to use as the login model is named "Install" because of the `rails generate devise: install` typo.

To fix:

- Change `devise_for :install` to `devise_for :users` (I assume that "User" is the model name, if not replace `:users` with the plural of the model name)
- Make sure you have a root route (`root to: "home#index"`)
- Configure the correct model [Devise Configure Model documents](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-models)
- Make sure the mailer is configured

That should work